# Sql join with multiple tables

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

```
mNumber     DateTime                  
3005877639  22/03/2017 12:04:55 PM
3459145987  17/04/2017 10:32:00 AM
3334386694  18/04/2017 4:37:10 PM
```

i have ownership information of mNumber in 3 different tables i.e table1, table2 and table3 such that table1 has ownership information of 3005877639, table2 has 3459145987 and table 3 has information about 3334386694. 
Now i want to retrieve ownership information of each number and join it with the above table. For some reason i cant combine the ownership information tables. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Assuming the desing of table1,table2 and table3 are the same simply union the tables using a cte or inline view and then join.  If you need further help please 1) include tablestructures for 1,2,3 2) define the expected results 3) include the database engine you're using (mySQL, SQL Server etc)  My assuption being that the mNumber is in each table; if not a conditional join may be needed.  Visual explaination of joins can be found: https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: this is simple join like select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.mNumber=t2.mNumber_column_name join table3 t3 on t1.mNumber=t3.mNumber_column_name where 1

Comment: Provide sample table data for all tables involved, and specify the expected result - formatted text here too. Tag the dbms you're using. And show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. Just like xQbert commented, i simply "union all" all 3 tables and used that as right-table in Left outer join i.e.

```
    Select a.*, b.Name,b.address from TableX as a Left Outer Join 
(Select * fom Table1 union all Select * from Table2 
union all Select * from Table3) as b on a.mNumber = b.mNumber
```

and it worked.

it is also worth mentioning that nested join doesn't work in this scenario. 
Thanks to all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
select * from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.mNumber=t2.mNumber_column_name join table3 t3 on t1.mNumber=t3.mNumber_column_name where 1 //if you want you can more condition
```

if you want to know more about join check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)